# bootstrap cpan without make

Tags: perl-module, cpan, perl

I want to use the `cpan` tool get a library from CPAN (`HTTP::Tiny::Multipart`).  (Or should I be using something else??)  It is written in pure Perl so I hope I don't need make for this.  Can this be done?

At first I couldn't get things to download at all, but eventually I found out the issue was proxies, and now with the right environment variables set I can successfully reach CPAN.  But now I get error messages about a missing make.

Comment: I see Mime::Base64 in the requirements, which requires XSLoader, meaning it probably needs to compile C code. So I believe the answer would be that you do need make.

Comment: A well behaved pure Perl module can be copied to a directory on your system `@INC`. The normal build process will do compatibility and dependency checks, and run the module's unit tests. It can't be that hard to get `make` onto your machine that you would give this up. What is your OS?

Comment: I happen to already have Base64.  I am on Windows; the Perl I am using is the one bundled with git for Windows.  (I also have Cygwin installed, which has its own Perl.)  I don't have admin rights on the machine, though there is a process to apply for them, if I can explain to the Powers That Be (tm) why I need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three common installers for Perl module distributions. To use these installers, one follows one of the following two sequences of steps:

```
perl Makefile.PL   # ExtUtils::MakeMaker or compatible
make
make test
make install
```

or

```
perl Build.PL      # Module::Build or compatible
./Build
./Build test
./Build install
```

`cpan` handles downloading the distributions and installing prerequisites, but it doesn't replace the distribution's installer. When it comes time to install a download distribution, it uses one of the above sequence (depending on whether the distribution includes a file named `Build.PL` or not).

`HTTP-Tiny-Multipart` (the distribution that provides HTTP::Tiny::Multipart) uses ExtUtils::MakeMaker as its installer, so installing it requires `make`.

---

The underlying issue is that you are using a gutted environment. It's not the purpose of `git` to provide `perl` to you.

If you want the full unix emulation environment for which `git` and its `perl` were built<sup>[1]</sup>, install Cygwin. Alternatively, you could also just as easily install a native Perl such as ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl.

---

1. Technically, `git` and its `perl` are built for MSYS, which is a subset of Cygwin.

Comment: You're using a gutted environment. If you want the full thing, download Cygwin.

Comment: I have a Cygwin as well, but that doesn't have make installed either.

Comment: So install it. And `git`. (No need to install git "for Windows" if you have Cygwin, because git "for windows" is really git for MSYS, which is a subset of Cygwin). You can do this by running the `setup` program found on their web site; it also acts as a package manager.

Comment: `make` is provided by the `make` package in the `Devel` category. `git` is provided by the `git` package in the `Devel` category.

Comment: Okay, you convinced me.  Installing Strawberry Perl.  I should have probably done this weeks ago.